# Leaflet Control Geocoder - Search box Bugs

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps

I am using Leaflet Control Geocoder package with my Leaflet map. I am having two issues with this package. I have the following code to initialise my map:

```
const map = L.map(
  'mapid', {
    renderer: L.canvas(),
    zoom: 18,
    zoomSnap: 0.5,
    keepInView: true,
    dragging: !L.Browser.mobile,
  }
).setMaxZoom(18).setMinZoom(1.5), 
    geocoder = new L.Control.Geocoder.Nominatim(),
    control = new L.Control.Geocoder({
      geocoder: geocoder,
      queryMinLength: 2,
      collapsed: false,
      suggestMinLength: 3,
      suggestTimeout: 150,
      placeholder: 'Search...'
    }).addTo(map);
```

1)  I currently have the control collapsed set to false, when I click inside the search box. The 'no results' found container is added. Nothing has been typed into the search box. Is this a bug with the package or is there a work around?

[image: Showing the no results found on click]

2) When you touch a location on an iOS device the dropdown list doesn't disappear but does on Android devices and hides the map

[image: Touching a location does not hide]